# Ansible populate variable for global use

Tags: variables, scope, ansible

Im having Ansible variable hell this week. I need to populate a variable dynamically during runtime, then it needs to be available for multiple tasks.

ie *myplaybook.yml*

```
---
- hosts: Healthcheck_Host 
  gather_facts: no
  become: "{{ True if deploy_user != '{{ deploy_user }}' else False }}"
  become_user: "{{ deploy_user }}"
  tasks:

    - name: "Get latest installed CL on groups['Healthcheck_Host'][0]"
      shell: |
        grep -oP '(?<=\:)(.*?)(?=\-)' {{ latest_deployed_build_dir.stdout }}/thebuildinfo.txt
      register: latest_stable_cl

    - debug:
        var: latest_stable_cl.stdout

    - name: Assign CL value from HC host
      set_fact:
        stable_cl_to_deploy: "{{ latest_stable_cl.stdout }}"
        cacheable: yes

- hosts: Appserver
  gather_facts: no
  become: "{{ True if deploy_user != '{{ deploy_user }}' else False }}"
  become_user: "{{ deploy_user }}"
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: stable_cl_to_deploy
```

In /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg I do have this set: **fact_caching = memory**

The debug output returns the value as expected from the 1st block, but once the second block is executed I am getting this error:

```
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'stable_cl_to_deploy' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/some/path/here/to/my/myplaybook.yml': line 30, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Set variables for tools package if deploying stable CL\n  ^ here\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: 'stable_cl_to_deploy' is undefined"
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`set_fact`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html) sets fact specific to host. In the example, `stable_cl_to_deploy` is added to the facts of `Healthcheck_Host` and referred in `Appserver`, hence the error.

Use ansible's [special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/refer%E2%80%A6) `hostvars` to access variables of other hosts like:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: hostvars['Healthcheck_Host'].stable_cl_to_deploy
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that still gives:

Friday 24 July 2020  16:38:48 +0000 (0:00:00.313)       0:00:05.378 *********** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "hostvars['Healthcheck_Host'].stable_cl_to_deploy": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

I copy and pasted what you wrote.

Comment: this works!

    - debug:
        var: hostvars['groups['Healthcheck_Host']'].stable_cl_to_deploy

thank you!